# wordpress show category link instead of post link

Tags: posts, categories, get-posts

I'm running WordPress on **localhost** using **XAMPP**.
I have a few posts and added them to a specific category (for example cat1 and cat2).

I've added the categories to the menu, and when I click on the menu I can see the post names and details. But the issue is the post's URL is same to the category.

Look at the image :

[image]

I want to see post after the click (or hover it). How to solve it?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @MaxYudin which code you mean? tell me, i will put the code here.(Sorry, im not expert)

Comment: The code you use to generate and print the menu.

Comment: @MaxYudin did you mean this code?             <nav id="masternav" class="clearfix">

                <?php wp_nav_menu( array(

                    'theme_location' => 'menu',

                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',

                    'menu_class' => 'sf-menu',

                    'fallback_cb' => 'default_menu'

                )); ?>

            </nav>

Comment: The code should not go to the comment, but to the question where you can format it for readability. And your problem is a plugin or the theme you use. Disable all plugins, switch the theme to a default and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the **loop-entry.php** there is

`<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>`

change above code to

`<h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>`

Done!